# Set a variable with tuple value in mysql shell

Tags: mysql, variables

I am setting a variable like this in mysql shell

```
mysql> set @nilesh := 330;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

which is working fine, but when I was trying to set a tuple to it,

```
mysql> set @nilesh := (330, 221);
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I am getting an error, Please suggest me how to initialize a variable with a tuple for mysql.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can't use a `Tuple` in SQL. I'd suggest you split it into 2 columns.

Comment: I wanna select these users data only, so one I'll set this variable. I'll do the query like this. select * from table_name where user_type_id in nilesh; where nilesh is my tuple variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it that way and it's not very clear why you'd want it. But you can do something similar dynamic-sql way

```
mysql> set @ids = '1, 2';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @sql = concat('select * from table1 where id in (', @ids, ')');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @sql;
+-----------------------------------------+
| @sql                                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
| select * from table1 where id in (1, 2) |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> prepare stmt from @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> execute stmt;
+------+-----------+------+
| id   | col1      | col2 |
+------+-----------+------+
|    1 | value1    |   11 |
|    2 | value2    |   12 |
+------+-----------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> deallocate prepare stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```